Is $\sqrt{3}$ in the field of 7-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_7$?
I am trying to solve the following question:
Show that $\sqrt{3} \notin \mathbb{Q}_7$, where $\mathbb{Q}_p$ means the field of $p$-adic numbers.
My approach was based on examining the quadratic residues modulo 7 and lifting the argument to $\mathbb{Q}_7$. My steps:

Quadratic Residues Modulo 7: Calculated the squares of all elements in $\mathbb{F}_7$ (the field of integers modulo 7) and noted that the set of squares is ${0, 1, 4, 2}$. Since 3 is not included in this set, it implies that 3 is not a quadratic residue modulo 7.

Extension to $\mathbb{Q}_7$: From the result above, I inferred that since there is no integer $x$ such that $x^2 \equiv 3 \pmod{7}$, there should be no element in $\mathbb{Q}_7$ (the field of $7$-adic numbers) satisfying $x^2 = 3$.


Would love it if anyone could confirm the correctness of this approach or suggest your own. Thanks!

Thanks! Your first argument shows validly that there is no square root of $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7$. I think the second argument needs a couple more words (you seem to be saying "if an equation has no solution in $\mathbb{Z}_7$, then it has no solution in $\mathbb{Q}_7$," but that's not literally true, for example, $7x - 1 = 0$, you need to use something about the equation).
One quick argument to finish it off (others will work too): what would be the $7$-adic valuation of a hypothetical square root of $3$ in $\mathbb{Q}_7$?

Another way to go: since $x^2-3$ is monic, $\sqrt 3$ would be an algebraic integer and thus in $\Bbb Z_p$....

First, this is the same problem with finding the solution of the equation $x^2 = 3$ on $\Bbb Q_7$. Now $x^{2} = 3$ implies $v_7(x^2) = v_7(3) = 0  \iff v_7(x) = 0$ so $x \in \Bbb Z_{7}$. So we can write $x = a_0 + a_17 + a_27^2+\cdots$, where $a_{i}$ is an integer between $0$ and $6$. This $x^2 = 3$ gives $a_0^2 \equiv 3 \bmod{7}$. But there is no $a_0$ such that $a_0^2 \equiv 3 \bmod{7}$ holds.
Note that every integer is of one of the forms:
$$7k,7k\pm1, 7k\pm2, 7k\pm3 k\in\Bbb Z$$
So we get:
$$(7k)^2 = 49k^2 \equiv 0 \bmod7$$
$$(7k \pm 1)^2 = 49k^2\pm 14k + 1 \equiv 1 \bmod7$$
$$(7k \pm 2)^2 = 49k^2\pm 28k + 4 \equiv 4 \bmod7$$
$$(7k \pm 3)^2 = 49k^2\pm 42k + 9 \equiv 2 \bmod7$$
None of these are $\equiv 3 \bmod7$, so no solutions exist.
That implies our assumption is wrong and there doesn't exist any solution of the equation $x^2 = 3$ in $\Bbb Q_7$, that is $\sqrt{3} \notin \Bbb Q_7$.
